# Count moving average in circle 360 degrees

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data

```
degree, value

0.0,0.42105263157894735
1.0,0.47368421052631576
2.0,0.47368421052631576
3.0,0.47368421052631576
4.0,0.5
5.0,0.5
6.0,0.5
7.0,0.47368421052631576
8.0,0.47368421052631576
9.0,0.47368421052631576
10.0,0.39473684210526316
..............
350.0,0.5263157894736842
351.0,0.5526315789473685
352.0,0.47368421052631576
353.0,0.47368421052631576
354.0,0.47368421052631576
355.0,0.4473684210526316
356.0,0.4473684210526316
357.0,0.4473684210526316
358.0,0.42105263157894735
359.0,0.42105263157894735
```

So, it is circle from 0 to 359 degrees.
I want to build moving average using these values. I do it with:

```
df['smoothing'] = df['value'].rolling(window=10).mean()   

    degree      value  smoothed
0      0.0   0.526316       NaN
1      1.0   0.000000       NaN
2      2.0   0.000000       NaN
3      3.0   0.000000       NaN
4      4.0   0.000000       NaN
..     ...        ...       ...
355  355.0   0.000000  0.000000
356  356.0   0.447368  0.044737
357  357.0   0.500000  0.094737
358  358.0   0.526316  0.147368
359  359.0   0.500000  0.197368
```

But there is a problem: I loose values from 0 to 9. They are important for me.
So, my script must use degrees 351,352,353,354,355  and so on to count average for degrees 0,1,2,3....

I expect output:

```
    degree      value                     smoothed
0      0.0   0.526316  mean value of 351-0 degrees
1      1.0   0.000000  mean value of 352-1 degrees
2      2.0   0.000000  mean value of 353-2 degrees
3      3.0   0.000000  mean value of 354-3 degrees
4      4.0   0.000000  mean value of 355-4 degrees
................
and so on
```

How to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prepend the last `9` values to the dataframe before taking the `rolling` `mean` so that `0` get's the mean value of `351-0`, `1` gets the mean value of `352-1` and so on:

```
df1 = df[-9:].append(df)
df['smoothed'] = df1['value'].rolling(window=10).mean().dropna()
```

---

```
    degree     value  smoothed
0      0.0  0.421053  0.457895
1      1.0  0.473684  0.450000
2      2.0  0.473684  0.450000
3      3.0  0.473684  0.450000
4      4.0  0.500000  0.452632
5      5.0  0.500000  0.457895
6      6.0  0.500000  0.463158
7      7.0  0.473684  0.465789
8      8.0  0.473684  0.471053
9      9.0  0.473684  0.476316
10    10.0  0.394737  0.473684
....
....
```

Comment: It is possible without pre-appending the dataframe by using indices. `df['smoothed'] = df.loc[np.hstack((df.index.values[-9:], df.index.values)), 'value'].rolling(window=10).mean()[9:]`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like, logically, you're looking for a *circular* sliding window, where, for example, 120 would average things from 101 to 120, but 0 would average things from 351 to 0.

Unfortunately, Pandas doesn't support that, but you can translate the values to force it to do so. Simply copy the value 351 to -9, 352 to -8, and so on, then take a rolling average (obviously keeping the positive angles only)